# Range of values for optimization?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> **Example 1:**  A window is being built and the bottom is a rectangle and the top is a semicircle.  If there is 12 meters of framing materials what must the dimensions of the window be to let in the most light?

**PLEASE SEE THE FOLLOWING IMAGE:** http://home.comcast.net/~ruhlep/optimization_problems_files/image004.jpg

Define $r$ to be the radius of the semi circle
$$P = \pi r + 2r + 2h$$
$$P = r(\pi + 2) + 2h$$

My teacher that there is a physical constraint of $0 < r < 12$, in order for the window to be physically possibly.

Why isn't the constraint:

$$0 < r(\pi + 2) < 12$$
$$0 < r < \frac{12}{\pi + 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is the potential for the rectangle to have zero height and in that case,  $$r=\frac{12}{\pi+2}$$ is the solution as it would use all the framing materials on just the semi-circle component.  If you change the inequality in the second part, then I could see the constraint being allowed.  Thus,

$$ 0 < r \leq \frac{12}{\pi+2}$$

would be the constraint I'd imagine though this does require that perimeter formula to be deduced.